# How to retrieve mongodb field value stored as array of string into a java ArrayList

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Document structure is:

```
db.lookupdata.insert({ parent_key : "category" , key :    "accessories" , value : ["belts","cases","gloves","hair","hats","scarves","sunglasses","ties","wallets","watches"]})
```

i want to store array filed values in java array list
i am finding the document like this:

```
 FindIterable<Document> iterable1 = docCollectionLookup.find(Filters.eq("parent_key", "category"));
        Iterator<Document> iter1=iterable1.iterator();
        while(iter1.hasNext())
        {
            Document theObj = iter1.next();

            categotyLookUpMap.put(theObj.getString("key"), list);

        }
```

now here how can i retrieve array field values(key:"value") in ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve array field values(key:"value") in ArrayList just like how you retrieve string field key. Please refer below:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable1 = docCollectionLookup.find(Filters.eq("parent_key", "category"));
Iterator<Document> iter1=iterable1.iterator();

//Create a HashMap variable with type <String,ArrayList>,according to your needs 
Map<String,ArrayList> categotyLookUpMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();

while(iter1.hasNext())
{
   Document theObj = iter1.next();
   //Get method of Document class will return object,parse it to ArrayList
   categotyLookUpMap.put(theObj.getString("key"), (ArrayList)theObj.get("value"));
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) which is MongoDB object-document mapper in Java. You can setup dependency / download JAR from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases)

First, create LookupData class to map to lookupdata collection. Annotation @Id is required else will throw exception with message "No field is annotated with @Id; but it is required". So create an _id field for it.

```
@Entity("lookupdata")
public class LookupData {

@Id
String _id ;

@Property("parent_key")
String parentKey;

String key;

ArrayList<String> value;

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}
public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getParentKey() {
    return parentKey;
}

public void setParentKey(String parentKey) {
    this.parentKey = parentKey;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void setValue(ArrayList<String> value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public ArrayList<String> getValue() {
    return value;
}

}
```

Retrieve array field values as below:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost"));

Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.map(LookupData.class);           

//lookupdata collection is under my local db "tutorials" in this case
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "tutorials");
Map<String,ArrayList> categotyLookUpMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList>();

LookupData lookupData = datastore.find(LookupData.class).get();
categotyLookUpMap.put(lookupData.getKey(), lookupData.getValue());
```